# Delete a record from a database and DataGridView at the same time using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, ssms

I have a `DataGridView` that extracts data from the database linked to SQL Server Manangement Studio and shows it on the `DataGridView`.

I have a `Delete` button that allows a user to delete a specific record using this code:

```
string SQLdelete = "DELETE FROM User WHERE Id = @RowID";

SqlParameter RowParameter = new SqlParameter();

SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand();
deleteRecord.Connection = con;
deleteRecord.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
deleteRecord.CommandText = SQLdelete;

RowParameter.ParameterName = "@RowID";
RowParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
RowParameter.IsNullable = false;
RowParameter.Value = rowIndex + 1;

deleteRecord.Parameters.Add(RowParameter);

deleteRecord.Connection.Open();
deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();
deleteRecord.Connection.Close();
```

The problem is that after deleting multiple records, I think the `RowID` gets mixed up and for example if I have a Data ID from 6-8 *(That's their IDs that are linked to the delete query)*, it doesn't get deleted and sometimes when I click on the ***3rd record***, the ***1st record*** gets deleted.

I don't know if I'm clear enough but if you want me to add any information I'll let you know.

I think it has to do with the `DataGridView`'s `RowID` and my table's `ID`; they get mixed up when I delete many records.

Can someone tell me what should I add in my *delete code* to avoid this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know why you can delete from table by DataGridView's rowId, they are difference. You should delete records by table's Id.

Comment: I'm trying to delete a selected row on DataGridView and at the same time delete the same record from the table. How do I link these two? I thought about the table's ID and the datagridView's RowID but they keep getting mixed up.

Comment: Get "ID" cell of selected row, then delete record from table by this cell value.

Comment: I'm using this variable: 
int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);

and this is the ID of the DataGridView's selected record, but when I have table data's ids that are different ( like I deleted the first three records and My data is from 3-8) that's when the IDs get mixed up, and even when I click on that rowid to delete it, it doesn't get deleted from the database.

Comment: RowIndex is not row ID, it always changes follow the number of rows added or removed, it is not ID field in database table too. You have to get "ID" cell value of your selected row, or the ID of selected record to delete it in DB correctly.

Comment: I just tested what you said now and it worked! I changed that RowID into the Cell's ID and now when I click on a record from the DataGridView, the same record gets deleted. Can you tell me how to also remove that selected record from the DataGridView when I click delete? I think because I changed that RowID into Cell's ID, it shows me this error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'" My current code is : 
int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value);
 dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);

Thanks a loot for your help!

Comment: Nevermind it works now I used the RowID to delete the selected row from the datagridview when I click on Delete, thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @MusicIsUniversal If you're binding your database table to your DataGridView, then you shouldn't have to manually delete anything from your DataGridView.  Just lookup the selected data object bound to the selected row and perform a delete on the database table using the ID value in the row, then re-bind your DataGridView and it'll refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to delete the records using the "ID" present in the table.

Means you need to bind the "ID" to datagridview, and "ID" present in the datagridview need to pass as parameter to query, and needs to delete the record.